Ignore Missing Columns when reading CSV file with Schema
EDIT: I have a csv file which I read using the below schema.
file_schema = StructType([
     StructField("col_A", StringType(), True),
     StructField("_corrupt_record", StringType(), True)
])

df_src = (spark.read.format('csv')
                    .option("inferSchema",False)
                    .option("header",True)
                    .schema(file_schema)
                    .option("columnNameOfCorruptRecord", "_corrupt_record")
                    .load(src_file_location)
                    .cache())

At some point of time in the future, I expect another column col_B to appear in the source file, however I have no control over when this is going to happen for complicated reasons. In the normal course of action, I'd have simply updated my schema as below and continued merrily.
file_schema = StructType([
     StructField("col_A", StringType(), True),
     StructField("col_B", LongType(), True), # New column
     StructField("_corrupt_record", StringType(), True)
])

Since I don't know when a new column is going to appear, I'm looking for a way to update my schema to include the new column, however if col_B is missing in the source file, it should get ignored, instead of putting the whole row in the corrupt_record column. Is there a way to achieve it without reading the file twice?

Can you give an example of what you are trying to achieve? The question is not very clear to me

Updated the problem description. Hopefully it makes sense now.

Look at nice article :
https://medium.com/@patidar.rahul8392/dealing-with-bad-or-corrupt-records-in-apache-spark-bab64b4d24b3
What do you want :
1/ readCSV on error if some line do not have all columns ?
set option "mode" on

DROPMALFORMED: ignores the whole corrupted records. This mode is
unsupported in the CSV built-in functions.
FAILFAST: throws an exception when it meets corrupted records.

doc : https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.5.1/sql-data-sources-csv.html
2/ error line on corrupted_record column :
When I execute your code it works for
input :
id,col_a,col_int,col_b
A,col_A_A,1,new_col_a
B,col_A_B,col_int,new_col_b
C,col_A_C,-55

output :



id
col_A
col_int
col_B
_corrupt_record




A
col_A_A
1
new_col_a
null


null
null
null
null
B,col_A_B,col_int...


C
col_A_C
-55
null
C,col_A_C,-55



Code (in java but very similar with python/scala)
        StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[] {
                DataTypes.createStructField("id",  DataTypes.StringType, true),
                DataTypes.createStructField("col_A",  DataTypes.StringType, true),
                DataTypes.createStructField("col_int",  DataTypes.IntegerType, true),
                DataTypes.createStructField("col_B", DataTypes.StringType, true),
                DataTypes.createStructField("_corrupt_record", DataTypes.StringType, true)
        });

        Dataset<Row> ds = ss.read()
                .option("header", "true")
//                .option("mode","DROPMALFORMED") //if you need to
                .option("columnNameOfCorruptRecord", "_corrupt_record")
                .schema(schema)
                .csv("file.csv");


only if you know its going to be col_B, we can also do something like this, for 'n' columns you can loop
if (df.columns.contains("col_B")) df else df.drop("col_B")


I don't know the names of additional columns.
